# What does reportId in Chrome HID API do?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I am trying to build an application using Google's great [HID API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/hid).

I don't, however, understand, what is meant by `reportId` in their API.

It's used throughout all the HID API in most of the calls, but it's never explained anywhere.

In a code I am using as a reference code, they use a magic constant with a coment `// TODO: where did this number come from?!`, which is far from ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not a Chrome thing, but a HID thing. There are many pages that seem to explain that, this is the first I found (maybe there are better)

http://eleccelerator.com/tutorial-about-usb-hid-report-descriptors/